# what do i do if im unable to pray due to being at school?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, school

I'm a student who lives in america, my school is mostly christian and we don't have very many Muslim student's i'm afraid it would be unacceptable to pray at school due to the setting being not very clean and staff not allowing me, does this mean I have to make up my prayers after school? Is that acceptable? I'm sorry if this sounds like a silly question I am just starting to learn prayer this year. Thank you.

Comment: Ask a scholar not here

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions asked on the site and also answers. Search before asking duplicate questions. Prayer is fard for any person while seeking knowledge is fard kifaya. One can pray anywhere if one is willing to find a workaround and school or work is not a valid excuse no matter where you are.

Comment: If it is a secular school you are studying in then perhaps it is Haram to study there. I am not giving a fatwa, I just have serious reasons to think so.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing is to pray when the time comes, even if you cannot necessarily do it perfectly. You can perform the prayer while simply sitting in a chair, if there is no option for proper sajdah, just do a nod and a short bow in place of rukuh/sujjud. You can even do tayyamum (symbolic/dry wudhu) if water is not nearby for preparing.

If you don't pray it at the time, you have to do it later, as soon as convenient, and before whatever prayer's time has come (i.e. in the same order as if you were saying them at their proper time).

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion to ask a scolar is valid but I (in a similarsituation but working) I didn't really succeed asking other muslims, they felt bad because they didn't practice.
You can put a light carpet and pray almost anywhere (except the toilet or so).
You will probably have to go through it and practise openly, although it has become more difficult after Al-Khaida and IS. You will have to explain to the companions that Islam is something different.
You can make compromises for praying times, delaying Zuhr to the next break before Asr, and delaying Asr to the next break before sunset.